# how to treat empty cells

Tags: sql-server, null, isnull

I am using SQL Server and I have a manager that just left. When I pull the record for sales, the section that shows the manager's name is empty for that team's orders. How can I make it so it shows the word OPEN when that happens?

I tried

```
Select
    Sales_Rep_Name,
    isnull([manager_name],'open') As [Manager Name]
From 
    Salestable
```

but it didn't work. I also tried a case

```
Select
    Sales_Rep_Name,
    case    
       when [MANAGER_NAME] is null 
          then 'open'
          else [MANAGER_NAME]
    end as [Manager Name]
From
    SalesTable
```

The query works but the cells still show empty. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the whole query? Thanks

Comment: @christos I just updated the full query.

Comment: You might have forgotten something. Is there any join you have left out of your post? The `b` alias should refer to a table that doesn't exist in you current query.

Comment: Guessing: `[MANAGER_NAME]` is not `null` - it's the empty string, `''`. Try comparing to that in your `case` statement instead.

Comment: To expand on @Blorgbeard probably correct guess, try something like: `CASE WHEN TRIM([MANAGER_NAME]) = '' THEN 'Open' ELSE [MANAGER_NAME] END as [MANAGER_NAME]` and see if that catches everything. Chances are you have a non-null string like `''` or some white space hanging out in there like `'   '`.

Comment: We deal with this a lot here and it is pretty common to see something like `ISNULL([MANAGER_NAME],'') = ''` to find anywhere that something is null or an empty string. Could add trim onto that to also get strings that are just spaces.

Comment: @jnevill & Evan I just verified that the cell actually has a space. I switched the case to = ' ' and it works now. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

@jnevill & Evan I just verified that the cell actually has a space. I switched the case to = ' ' and it works now. Thank you guys.